# Uniqueness validation with a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, unique-constraint

My model structure is as follows:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :charts
end

class Chart < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :client
   has_many :chart_data
end

class ChartDatum < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :chart
end
```

ChartDatum has an attribute called 'name' which needs to be unique for each client.
I tried using  **"validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => [:chart_id]"**  but this helped me getting a unique key for a particular chart but not for all charts for a particular client. I am looking for something like **"validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => [:client_id]"** but obviously with the current structure it will not work out.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: You want same key for all the chart_data that belong to a particular client ?

Comment: I want unique chart_data for each client.

Comment: But its not associted directly...

Comment: Its a business requirement. so although there is not a direct relationship I want to have this uniqueness constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need unique `name` for chart_data for each client, you can try writing a custom validation for name something like this :

```
class ChartDatum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chart
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true, unless => :unique_for_client?

  def unique_for_client?
    client = self.chart.client
    client.charts.chart_data.pluck(:name).include?(self.name)
  end
end
```